# Search sorting inSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 4 columns (LastName, FirstName, Title, City) in a table (MSSQL2008). I want to display search results in a way that if search word matches in full it should come first then all the other results for any column. For example if I have following table

```
LastName    FirstName   Title   City
Kirk        Yang        Sales Rep   Seattle
Fuller      Andrew      Vice Pred   Tacoma
Leverling   Janet       Sales Rep   Kirkland
Peacock     Margaret    Sales Rep   Redmond
Jacob       Kirk        Sales Mag   London
Suyama      Michael     Sales Rep   London
King        Robert      Sales Rep   London
Callahan    Laura       Sales Cord  Seattle
David       Kirkpatrk   Sales Rep   London
```

and if someone search for **kirk** then result should be:

```
    LastName    FirstName   Title   City
    Kirk        Yang        Sales Rep   Seattle        
    Jacob       Kirk        Sales Mag   London
    Leverling   Janet       Sales Rep   Kirkland
    David       Kirkpatrk   Sales Rep   London
```

Edit:
I am using UNION ALL with SELECT to get the results (naive, I guess), also tired CASE but unable to get the desired result

Comment: Although you already got the answer you were looking for, it's a good practice to tell what you've alreay done. This will avoid peoplo to downgrade your question, as you'll be demonstrating that you put some effort trying to solve the problem yourself before posting the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me assume that you are using `like` for the search and not full text search.

If so, you can do this as:

```
order by ((case when LastName = 'kirk' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when FirstName = 'kirk' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when Title = 'kirk' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when City = 'kirk' then 1 else 0 end)
         ) desc,
         ((case when LastName like '%kirk%' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when FirstName like '%kirk%' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when Title like '%kirk%' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when City like '%kirk%' then 1 else 0 end)
         ) desc
```

This actually does a little more than you ask for.  It returns the rows with the most exact matches first.  Then it returns the rows with the most partial matches first.

Comment: +1 This is a really nice solution.

Comment: I am not sure is it right place to ask (people downgrade :-)), can you kindly explain. and with some modification, it is working for me, thanks